# Write to a file mysql commands with ruby

Tags: ruby, escaping

I am using a program that write sql commands in a file.

The program is in ruby. I found out that it does not escape properly special chars.

I found the function that does the escaping but its not completely correct.

```
def escape_for_sql(s)
    s=s.to_s
    if s.nil?
    "''"
    else
        "'"+ s.gsub("'","\'")+"'"
    end
end
```

Never used ruby before, so does someone can provide me a correct function or even better to
tell me if there is any built in method?

p.s. I cannot install any external module

Comment: You may need to provide more information, like... what's it doing wrong vs. what you expect.

Comment: @Dave the code I posted it just escapes character ' . Does it seems correct to you?
Mysql escaping it depends from server configuration. I asked if anyone has a relatively safe mysql escaping function that works in most mysql installations. I know that the correct way is to use the ruby Mysql module and use it's escape function. This cannot be done because I cannot install anything on the machine the code runs. I think the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want this method to convert occurrences of `'` in the string `s` to `\'`, this should work:

```
def escape_for_sql(s)
  s=s.to_s
  if s.nil?
    "''"
  else
    "'" + s.gsub("'") { %q{\'} } + "'"
  end
end

puts escape_for_sql "hello, this 'is' a string"
# => 'hello, this \'is\' a string'
```

In the original method, the replacement was wrapped in double quotes, so the backslash wasn't getting inserted.

**EDIT**

Note: to replace all MySQL special characters, do something like below. I've only included a few of the MySQL special characters--for a full list check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html. Also note that there are security concerns with using a custom escaping method.

```
def escape_for_sql(s)
  s=s.to_s
  if s.nil?
    "''"
  else
    literals = %w{ % ' " \r \n }
    literals.each do |x|
      s.gsub!(/#{x}/) { '\\' + x }
    end
    "'" + s + "'"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. I want to escape all mysql special characters although